# Bootstraps alignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ejs, semantic-ui

I am using a combination of bootstrap and semantics ui to style and align my webpage. I am currently having an issue with align my pages api map and blog post across the page together rather it is stack on top of each other like in the image showed[image]

Here is my underlying code, I am using node.js and as well ejs

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

<div class="container-show">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="lead">Neighborhood Inscope</p>
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9"></div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="ui huge header">
                    <%= blog.title %>
                </div>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= blog.image %>" >
                <p>
                    <strong>By <%= blog.author.username %></strong>
                </p>
                <div class="content">
                    <span><%= blog.created.toDateString() %></span>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <p><%- blog.body %></p>
                </div>
                <% if(currentUser && blog.author.id.equals(currentUser._id)){ %>
                    <a class="ui orange mini basic button" href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/edit">Edit</a>
                    <form id="delete-form" action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <button class="ui red mini basic button">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                <% } %>            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="well">
            <div class="text-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/new">Add new comment</a>
            </div>
        <% blog.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class ="col-md-12">
                    <h5 id="comment-date" class="pull-right">
                    <%= comment.created.toDateString() %>
                    </h5>
                    <strong><%= comment.author.username %> </strong>
                    <p><%= comment.text %></p>
            <% if(currentUser && comment.author.id.equals(currentUser._id)){ %>
                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" 
                    href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/<%= comment._id %>/edit">
                        Edit
                </a>
                <form id="delete-mini-button" action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/<%= comment._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="Delete">
                </form>
            <% } %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% }) %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're immediately closing the `.col-md-9` element.